# PHP array throws error when trying to load another array inside it

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I am finding the following error:
"Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given..."

This happens in the following piece of code and only when I added input fields to the form whose name was an array (so I could repeat the input multiple times). The line the error refers to is ($v=htmlspecialchars($value);)

```
if ($len > 2) {
    $values=array();
    $possible=array('orderId','source','date', 'clientPrice','firstName','lastName','email','address','city','zip');
    $i=1;
    $query2 = "UPDATE orders SET ";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $k=htmlspecialchars($key);
        $v=htmlspecialchars($value);
        if(in_array($k, $possible)) {
            $query2 .= $k." = ?";
            $values[]=$v;  //append values to an array for later use
            if($i < ($len-2)) $query2 .= ', ';
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of how to solve this and the reason for the error?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong. What do you need us to do?

Comment: Your `$_POST` array probably has values in it you don't realize exist. Or they have blank values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question in the first paragraph. You passed an array as values, therefore `$value` is going to be an array of the various inputs you assigned an array name to.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if ( ! is_array($value))
    {
        // Manage values that aren't arrays
    }
}
```

Iterating over `$_POST` isn't really a good practice. You would be better assigning the actual names of the fields to their own variables or creating your own array with the exact data you need.

Comment: How could I just skip the posting if it is an array? I would like the array value not to be added into here...

Comment: do not hamper with all _POST variables. Take what you need and leave others alone :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not deal with all _POST values. Check only what you require. Try this code for a different approach, more correct.

```
foreach ($possible as $_possib) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$_possib])) continue;
    $query1 .= $_possib." = ?";
    $values[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$_possib]); // should be mysql_real_escape?
    if($i < ($len-2)) $query2 .= ', ';
    $i++;
}
```

By the way, please think about htmlspecialchars, since it is only for correct displaying in html form. It seems that you will submit these values to a database, so use relevant escape function.

Answer (score 0):

as the error states, at least one of your $_POST values appear to be an array.

try wrapping your htmlspecialchars() call within array_walk_recursive. i've also added an if(is_array()) check so as to only apply it when needed.

```
if(is_array($value)) array_walk_recursive(htmlspecialchars($value));
```

alternatively, you may want to var_dump($_POST) to see which input fields are appearing as an array, and maybe tweak your form accordingly if this is undesirable behavior.